# ReplayKit2 - Begin Broadcast Directly From App

Tags: ios, objective-c, replaykit

In the past, if you wanted to use ReplayKit to stream video to your app, the user had to exit the app, go to Settings, enable the Screen Broadcasting option, swipe to open the Control Panel, and long press the broadcasting button; after completing these steps, the Start Broadcast screen appears.

I have since seen an app which is live on the app store which is able to directly display the Start Broadcast screen from the app without any of these steps. This is definitely new functionality, but I haven't read anything anywhere about it. This is working even when the phone has never enabled screen recording permissions. I can't post a video here, but I'll add a screenshot of the screen I want to display from my app.

How can I programmatically display this screen inside my app without going through the other steps I mentioned (in objective-c)? This is a much better user flow and I would like to implement it this way.

[image]